# About a loss of precision when calculating an aggregate sum with data frames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have a Dataframe with this kind of data:

```
unit,sensitivity currency,trading desk  ,portfolio       ,issuer        ,bucket ,underlying ,delta        ,converted sensitivity
ES  ,USD                 ,EQ DERIVATIVES,ESEQRED_LH_MIDX ,5GOY          ,5      ,repo       ,0.00002      ,0.00002
ES  ,USD                 ,EQ DERIVATIVES,IND_GLOBAL1     ,no_localizado ,8      ,repo       ,-0.16962     ,-0.15198
ES  ,EUR                 ,EQ DERIVATIVES,ESEQ_UKFLOWN    ,IGN2          ,8      ,repo       ,-0.00253     ,-0.00253
ES  ,USD                 ,EQ DERIVATIVES,BASKETS1        ,9YFV          ,5      ,spot       ,-1003.64501  ,-899.24586
```

and I have to do an aggregation operation over this data, doing something like this:

```
val filteredDF = myDF.filter("unit = 'ES' AND `trading desk` = 'EQ DERIVATIVES' AND issuer = '5GOY' AND bucket = 5 AND underlying = 'repo' AND portfolio ='ESEQRED_LH_MIDX'")
                     .groupBy("unit","trading desk","portfolio","issuer","bucket","underlying")
                     .agg(sum("converted_sensitivity"))
```

But I am seeing that I am loosing precision on the aggregated sum, so how can I be sure about that every value of "converted_sensitivity" is converted to a BigDecimal(25,5) before doing the sum operation over the new aggregated column?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could do a map operation to calculate the BigDecimal version of the column first, then add those up in the next operation.   I guess that would go between .groupBy and .agg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure of the convertion you can use the `DecimalType` in your DataFrame.

According to Spark documentation the `DecimalType` is:

> The data type representing java.math.BigDecimal values. A Decimal that must have fixed precision (the maximum number of digits) and scale (the number of digits on right side of dot).
>   The precision can be up to 38, scale can also be up to 38 (less or equal to precision).
>   The default precision and scale is (10, 0).

You can see this [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType).

To convert the data you can use the function `cast` of the `Column` object. Like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType

val filteredDF = myDF.filter("unit = 'ES' AND `trading desk` = 'EQ DERIVATIVES' AND issuer = '5GOY' AND bucket = 5 AND underlying = 'repo' AND portfolio ='ESEQRED_LH_MIDX'")
                 .withColumn("new_column_big_decimal", col("converted_sensitivity").cast(DecimalType(25,5))
                 .groupBy("unit","trading desk","portfolio","issuer","bucket","underlying")
                 .agg(sum("new_column_big_decimal"))
```

Comment: perfect @Thiago, just what I needed to know, thank you very much!